# How to get the high from a whole timeperiod in the past where one ema crossed above the other? Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I desperately need your help with a problem I face since 2 days now. I am not able to get the result I want.
I do want to store the high price of a candle inside a variable for later use and also draw a horizontal line where the high has happened. The issue is, that I want the high from a whole period (but not the most recent one!!) where one ema crossed above the other. I want the high from the period in the past before the current one. Basically the last time when it happend. I hope I expressed it clearly but for more detail, please see the picture:

High from the past period where one ema crossed above the other

[image: 1]

I am however able to get the price from the current period since the emas have crossed with:

```
GetHighestSince(condition, series=high) =>
    var float highestValueSince = na
    if condition or series > highestValueSince
        highestValueSince := series
    highestValueSince
```

Unfortunately this data is not what I need. I tried using for loops but I am not able to get what I want. I am still new to coding and having a hard time understanding that every candle is triggering a complete new run of the script. That makes it so hard for me.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// @eldlr

//@version=5
indicator("Test", overlay=true)
emaGreen = ta.sma(close, 7)
emaRed = ta.sma(close, 30)

barsBack = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(emaGreen, emaRed))
// this needs to be increased by 1 because the evaluation trigger condition can only be true on a latter bar
highestOffset = ta.highestbars(high, nz(barsBack) + 1)

var int highestBar = na
// your period is over, offset is final
if ta.crossunder(emaGreen, emaRed)
    // if offset 0 we need to reduce it by 1 in order to exclude current candle after condition close
    highestBar := bar_index + (highestOffset == 0 ? -1 : highestOffset)
    label.new(highestBar, high, "Highest " + str.tostring(highestOffset), yloc = yloc.abovebar)
plot(emaGreen, color = color.green )
plot(emaRed, color = color.red)
```